# Should I prepare my containers to be compatible with ranges?

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator, c++14

I am coding my own special container, I want them to be as compatible with STL as possible, including C++14, and modern STL? Even C++17 perhaps.

Should I prepare it to handle ranges? (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges)
Or should I concentrate in simply providing an iterator interface? For example begin and end?

```
class MyVector{
  class iterator{...}; // nested here for simplicity
  iterator begin(){...}
  iterator end(){...}
};
```

In what circumstances the iterator interface (including container and ierator traits) is not enough to build appropriate ranges?

Comment: Ranges are coming out no sooner than C++20, which is supposed to be released in 3 years. You have time to adapt your code to use ranges IMO before they are officially part of the Standard Library.

Comment: Sure, I can adapt later, but the question is mostly conceptual, to understand a modern design and to understand the possibilities that ranges bring. For example, if the reference type of the container is a proxy object (`reference != T&`) or if `begin` and `end` return different types.

Comment: @alfC: Neither of those things is allowed by the current standard library paradigm (well, proxies are allowed for OutputIterators and maybe InputIterators, but nothing else). So if you use them, you won't be able to use range-based `for` (outside of C++17), or use any of the standard library algorithms.

Comment: You should embrace the power of 'and'.

You can provide interator-based interface - so that people can use your code today (rather that three years from now), and then add additional functionality down the road.

Comment: This is strictly off-topic. It's pure opinion and speculation. My $.02 is to go with YAGNI. Don't introduce unnecessary complexity, if it's not zero cost, don't introduce it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "prepare it to handle ranges?" mean? Providing an iterator interface via `begin`/`end` *is* how you make something a range in C++ - this was as true in C++03 as it will be post-Ranges TS. It's just that in Ranges, `begin()` and `end()` don't have to have the same type.

Comment: @Barry, well in terms of type traits, access functions. I presume also that if the container is very traditional `begin` and `end` will suffice. But my containers have proxy references, for example.